# Appending null characters to regular characters

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, string, c-strings

I want to concatenate null characters with regular characters like so:

```
NSString *message = @"ABC";
NSUInteger length = [message length];
char char4 = length;
char char3 = length >> 8;
char char2 = length >> 16;
char char1 = length >> 24;
message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%c%c%c%@",char4,char3,char2,char1,message];
```

The problem is that the string stays at length 4 (and looks like `¿ABC`). How can I edit this code so that the null characters are also appended to the string?

**In reply to Mark's comment**

What I am trying to do here is append the length of the string to the beginning of the string, not in numerical format, but in the format of ascii characters (almost like a base 256 number). I would use the format, `@"%04c%@",length,message`, the problem is that the resulting string would be `000¿ABC` and zeroes have ascii value (48 in decimal to be exact) and so that defeats the purpose. The ASCII character that has decimal value 0 is the null character (`\0`) so I have to use that instead of 0. It is necessary that I have those leading null characters.

For the purposes of what I'm trying to accomplish, the following code works

```
NSUInteger length = [message length];
char char4 = length;
char char3 = length >> 8;
char char2 = length >> 16;
char char1 = length >> 24;

if (char4 == '\0')
    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\0%@",message];
else
    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%@",char4,message];

if (char3 == '\0')
    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\0%@",message];
else
    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%@",char3,message];

if (char2 == '\0')
    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\0%@",message];
else
    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%@",char2,message];

if (char1 == '\0')
    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\0%@",message];
else
    message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%@",char1,message];
```

But, if anybody can contribute something shorter or more intuitive, that'd be great.

Comment: the char variables are shifts on the length and nothing to do with the values of the string and putting ]0 in a string will not do anything (strings end with \0) what are you really trying to do?

Comment: You may put `NULL`s into an array of char, but you'll have to keep track of the length yourself as well as write your own print routines because most C standard library functions rely on strings being terminated with `NULL`.

Comment: Be wary, @hellork: ASCII NUL '\0' U+0000 is a character code; NULL is a null pointer constant.  These are not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this.  It's a bad idea.  For example, NSString is conceptually built on 16-bit Unicode characters, but you're trying to prepend bytes. Note that there's nothing guaranteeing that NSString's internal representation is UTF-16 or any other specific encoding.  In any case, when the string is written out it has to be converted to whatever encoding and that is unlikely to preserve your length prefixing in a way you can predict.

Use an NSData with the length in the first 4 (or maybe 8 would be better for a 64-bit length) bytes followed by the string *in a particular encoding*.  I recommend UTF-8.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why I didn't think to go ahead and just use NSData because that's what I was turning my NSString into anyway. Thanks